# How to remove punctuation from a string and remember the position of it from the string

Tags: string, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

Hello I have been trying to create a program which gets a string and removes all the punctuation and capitalisation, then the program should insert all the punctuation and capitalisation back into the sentence at the place were it came from.

Here is what I got so far;

```
sentence = 'I am called bob. What is your name?'
punc = ('!', '"', '£', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '¬', '`', '{', '}', '~', '@', ':', '?', '>', '<', ',', '.', '/', ';', '#', ']', '[', '/', '*')

Dictionary = {}
count = 0

for i in sentence:
    count = count + 1
    if i == punc:
        Dictionary[i] = count 

print(Dictionary)
```

I know it's not very much and it don't do anything(I don't know why) but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using python 3.4

Comment: Take the string, do whatever with it, and then throw that string away and use the original one again? Why do you want to reinsert the stuff after removing it?

Comment: Its for school a stupid task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable and therefore do not have an insert or remove method. However, you can change this to a list which is certainly mutatble. I'd probably have a dictionary with the punctuation as a key and a list of each index. The issue you may run into is that if you have multiple punctuation marks, there's no guarantee that they will be inserted in the correct order. For example:

```
sentence = 'I am called bob. What is your name?'
punc = ('!', '"', '£', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '¬', '`', '{', '}', '~', '@', ':', '?', '>', '<', ',', '.', '/', ';', '#', ']', '[', '/', '*')

sentence = list(sentence)
Dictionary = {}

for i, p in enumerate(sentence): # enumerate() returns an iterable in (index, value) format
    if p in punc:
        if p in Dictionary:
            Dictionary[p].append(i)
        else:
            Dictionary[p] = [i]

print(Dictionary) # => {'?': [34], '.': [15]}
```

For example, if I have a weirdly formatted string with a random amount of various punctuation marks:

```
sentence = 'I? am. cal?led ,bob. Wh,at. is your .name?.'
... # above code
print(sentence) # => "I? am. call?ed bob,. What .i,s your .name?."
```

This is obviously incorrect. The only sure-fire way is to iterate through the dict from the lowest element to the highest element and add them that way.

Final code:

```
original = sentence = 'I? am. cal?led ,bob. Wh,at. is your .name?.'
punc = ('!', '"', '£', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '¬', '`', '{', '}', '~', '@', ':', '?', '>', '<', ',', '.', '/', ';', '#', ']', '[', '/', '*')

sentence = list(sentence)
Dictionary = {}
seq = [] # list of all indices with any punctuation 

for i, p in enumerate(sentence):
    if p in punc:
        seq.append(i)
        if p in Dictionary:
            Dictionary[p].append(i)
        else:
            Dictionary[p] = [i]

sentence = list(filter(lambda x: x not in punc, sentence))
for i in seq:
    for key, indices in Dictionary.items():
        if i in indices:
            sentence.insert(i, key)
            indices.remove(i)
assert(''.join(sentence) == original)
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: How would I take out punctuation and capital letters and reinsert them both